# How do you determine if a WiX bundle installer is quiet or interactive?

Tags: wix, bundle

There two problems that I shoud solved. First,how do you determine if a WiX bundle installer is quiet or interactive? Second,how does a exe installer that maked by bundle of wix v3.8 can keep a slient installing with several parameters? Please give me help,thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Burn engine provides your Bootstrapper Application a struct with all the information from the command-line. In managed code the `Command` struct is provided to your class that inherits from `Bootstrapper`.

In the `Command` struct you'll get the `Display` enum that tells you whether the bundle is launched quite or passive or full UI. There is also the `GetCommandLineArgs()` to get additional command line arguments.

Comment: How to set these properties in bundle project? And also how to pass parameters?Thanks very much!

Comment: Could you provide a example ?? I have the same problem but don't know how to fix it